# Передача QR-кода / Штрих-кода

Tags: java, android, qrcode, barcode

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне надо передать отсканированный QR-кода / Штрих-кода в `TextView`. Вылетает ошибка.
Фрагмент кода где ошибка:

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // takeBarcodePicture();
                    PictureBarcodeActivity PBA = new PictureBarcodeActivity();
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                     if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(PBA.getPackageManager()) != null){
                        File photo;
                        try {
                            photo = File.createTempFile("IMG", ".jpg", PBA.getFilesDir());
                        }catch (Exception ex){
                            return;
                        }
                        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PBA,"com.mydomain.fileprovider", photo);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                         PBA.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "В доступе отказано !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Неожиданное значение: " + requestCode);
        }
    }
```

Ошибка (знаю что жалуется на `null` значение но не знаю как исправить):

```
 Process: com.example.application, PID: 20010
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:90)
        at com.example.application.PictureBarcodeActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(PictureBarcodeActivity.java:94)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$1.run(ActivityCompat.java:519)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-06 02:47:41.153 1517-3658/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
04-06 02:47:41.153 1517-3658/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.application"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.MANAGE_GNSS_DRIVERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.YOUR_PHONE_TYPE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android:windowSoftInputMode" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".PictureBarcodeActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScannedBarcodeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FragmentClientDocDate" />
        <activity android:name=".PhotoSave" />
        <activity android:name=".Fragment3" />
        <activity android:name=".Fragment2" />
        <activity android:name=".Fragment1" />
        <activity android:name=".MainFtagment" />
        <activity android:name=".PageFragment" />
        <activity android:name=".CustomDialogFragment" />
        <activity android:name=".ClientDocListDate" />
        <activity android:name=".ClientActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DocActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UserActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Здесь не хватает файла манифеста.

Comment: В манифесте нет блока `provider`. Добавьте его чтобы использовать `FileProvider`.

Comment: Добавил `provider` жалуется на это  `android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"`

Comment: Свежее пример найдите, с androidx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему другим способом, используя библиотеку `Zxing`. Вот код для тех кто столкнулся с такой же бедой:
Добавил зависимость в build

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0@aar'
```

Код сканера:

```
public class ScanZxing extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnScan;

    TextView tv_qr_readTxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_zxing);
        btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        tv_qr_readTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_qr_readTxt);


        btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ScanZxing.this);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.e("Scan*******", "Cancelled scan");

            } else {
                Log.e("Scan", "Scanned");

                tv_qr_readTxt.setText(result.getContents());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnScan"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:text="От сканируйте QR-код"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_qr_readTxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Тут можно найти способ как переделать для Fragment
https://medium.com/@dev.jeevanyohan/zxing-qr-code-scanner-android-implementing-in-activities-fragment-custom-colors-faa68bfc761d

Answer (score 2):

Коллега,

У вас в коде 3 ошибки:

1. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` - уже неактуален, начиная то ли c API 29 или 30 он обьявлен устаревщим и в 30-й по-моему вообще не работает. Соответственно файл надо создавать во внутреннем хранилище вашего приложения
2. Открытая передача `Uri` через `putExtra()` также уже давно запрещена, требуется его маскирование с помощью в данном случае `FileProvider`, где маскировка пути делается через `xml/provider_paths` (после подсказки @АндрейМихалев попытку ввести `FileProvider` у вас появилась, но неудачная - см. п. 3)
3. У вас везде используется `androidx`, а `FileProvider` вы пытаетесь использовать от `support`

Корректный код, приблизительно такой:

```
//REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE - идентификатор запроса, что-то типа 101
private void takePicture(Activity activity) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photo;
        try {
            photo=File.createTempFile("IMG", ".jpg", activity.getFilesDir());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.warn("Can't create photo file", ex);
            return;
        }
        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, "com.mydomain.fileprovider", photo);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
    else {
        logger.warn("No camera supporting intent is available!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибки устранил и воспользовался предложенным кодом. Но теперь выскакивает другая ошибка: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.app.Activity.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference`  и теперь я точно перестал что либо понимать )

Comment: @Darsi ну если вы передает `Activity` равным `null`, неужели вы ожидаете другой реакции?

Comment: `Activity` из которого вы вызываете код